# Nested table issue while printing document

Tags: css, html, pdf, html-table

I have a table which I am trying to print. So the basic structure is  contains a nested **table** both containing **thead**. Once I do a print, the pdf shows overlapping **thead**.

Please find attached link to reproduce the code. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0l0s7blh401tg7/table.html

[image: overlapping theads]

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>heading</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Heading 2</th>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>               
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css *(this only helps if you have a very plain thead an only one aswell)*:

```
thead { display: table-header-group }
tfoot { display: table-row-group }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid }
```

---

## Edit:

**Regarding your question:** The reason why your `thead` is overlapping is your `table` markup itself. Right now we have multiple `table` and `thead`, and also padding which is causing the overlapping. I did some research and found two different solutions you could use.

---

**Fact 1:** Only the lastest `thead` in your markup will be place on a second page when printed. Therefore you can check and adjust your table like this [working example here, print button on the top](https://jsfiddle.net/epj3ebc8/1/) :

```
<table>
    <!-- thead on first page -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ... </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <!-- thead on first page an all following -->
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> ... </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> ... </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Fact 2:** In my opinion the only working solution if you want all your thead information on all pages is to move all `th` in one `thead` at the top of the `table`, therefore you will have all informations on every page [working example for this solution, print button on the top](http://jsfiddle.net/6kEtv/)

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: the following css already exists

@media print {
   thead { display: table-header-group }
   tfoot { display: table-row-group }
   tr { page-break-inside: avoid }
}

thead { display: table-header-group }
tfoot { display: table-row-group }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid }

Comment: Hi, as soon as I add a row before the nested table. the error is back again. so your answer works on if the nested table is the child of the first row..
https://jsfiddle.net/epj3ebc8/2/

Comment: sorry @gerrit i didn't get you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151366/discussion-between-deepankar-and-gerrit-halfmann).